# Regex to insert space in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am a regex supernoob (just reading my first articles about them), and at the same time working towards stronger use of vim.  I would like to use a regex to search for all instances of a colon `:` that are not followed by a space and **insert** one space **between** those colons and any character after them.

If I start with:

```
foo:bar
```

I would like to end with

```
foo: bar
```

I got as far as `%s/:[a-z]` but now I don't know what do for the next part of the `%s` statement.

Also, how do I change the `:[a-z]` statement to make sure it catches anything that is not a space?

Comment: A trick I've found for developing my regex expressions is to use `/` to build the search term and get it to match exactly what I want it to and then run the replace with a blank search term. In Vim `%s//bar/g` will replace the previous search term with bar. This has made it much easier for me to explore what is possible for my search term without needing to try and copy the search term into the middle of my replace command

Comment: @SamBrinck's trick is especially useful when you have the `'incsearch'` option set since the text matching the search is highlighted as you type.  That makes it very easy to fiddle with the pattern and immediately see the results.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`:%s/:\(\S\)/: \1/g`

`\S` matches any character that is not whitespace, but you need to remember what that non-whitespace character is.  This is what the `\(\)` does.  You can then refer to it using `\1` in the replacement.

So you match a `:`, some non-whitespace character and then replace it with a `:`, a space, and the captured character.

---

Changing this to only modify the text when there's only one `:` is fairly straight forward.  As others have suggested, using some of the zero-width assertions will be useful.

`:%s/:\@!<:[^:[:space:]]\@=/: /g`

- `:\@!<` matches any non-`:`, including the start of the line.  This is an important characteristic of the negative lookahead/lookbehind assertions.  It's not requiring that there actually be a character, just that there isn't a `:`.
- `:` matches the required colon.
- `[^:[:space:]]` introduces a couple more regex concepts.

  - The outer `[]` is a collection.  A collection is used to match any of the characters listed inside.  However, a leading `^` negates that match.  So, `[abc123]` will match `a`, `b`, `c`, `1`, `2`, or `3`, but `[^abc123]` matches anything but those characters.
  - `[:space:]` is a character class.  Character classes can only be used inside a collection.  `[:space:]` means, unsurprisingly, any whitespace.  In most implementations, it relates directly to the result of the C library's `isspace` function.

  Tying that all together, the collection means "match any character that is not a `:` or whitespace".
- `\@=` is the positive lookahead assertion.  It applies to the previous atom (in this case the collection) and means that the collection is required for the pattern to be a successful match, but will not be part of the text that is replaced.

So, whenever the pattern matches, we just replace the `:` with itself and a space.

Comment: This only works on the first set of colons, though - try it on "an::example".  That may or may not suit @Lee's purposes.

Comment: Then the question needs clarification.  All that was stated was a colon followed by non-whitespace should have a space inserted between the colon and the following non-whitespace character.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Although my specific case had no double colons, it would be a cool addition to the answer if it's easy enough for you.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `%s/[^:]\zs:\ze[^ :]/: /g` will match only one colon followed by anything other than a space (or colon)

Answer (score 7):

You want to use a zero-width negative lookahead assertion, which is a fancy way of saying look  for a character that's not a space, but don't include it in the match:

```
:%s/: \@!/: /g
```

The `\@!` is the negative lookahead.

Comment: I never understood why to use a so different regex sintax in vim, is the thing I hate the most from vim (which is my fav editor btw).

Comment: The base for Vim's regex comes from vi, which comes from ex, which comes from ed and existed long before PCRE (which is what most people think of as "standard" regex, even though there is no such thing).  Really, it's the other regex syntaxes that are so different. ;)

Answer (score 7):

An interesting feature of Vim regex is the presence of `\zs` and `\ze`. Other engines might have them too, but they're not very common.

The purpose of `\zs` is to mark the start of the match, and `\ze` the end of it. For example:

```
ab\zsc
```

matches `c`, only if before you have `ab`. Similarly:

```
a\zebc
```

matches `a` only if you have `bc` after it. You can mix both:

```
a\zsb\zec
```

matches `b` only if in between `a` and `c`. You can also create zero-width matches, which are ideal for what you're trying to do:

```
:%s/:\zs\ze\S/ /
```

Your search has no size, only a position. And them you substitute that position by " ". By the way, `\S` means any character but white space ones.

`:\zs\ze\S` matches the position between a colon and something not a space.

Comment: `\zs` and `\ze` are essentially shortcuts for a variable-width positive lookbehind and lookahead assertions, respectively.  `\zs` is the same as `\%(pattern before zs\)\@<=` and `\ze` is the same as `\%(pattern after ze\)\@=` is the same as `\ze`.  So, although it's overly verbose for this simple example, you could also use `:%s/\%(:\)\@<=\%(\S\)\@=/ /g`.

Answer (score 5):

you probably want to use `:[^ ]` to mach everything except spaces. As mentioned by Matt this will cause your replace to replace the extra character.
There are several ways to avoid this, here are 2 that I find useful.
1) Surround the last part of the search term with parenthesis `\(\)`, this allows you to reference that part of the search in your replace term with a `/1`.
Your final replace string should look like this:

```
%s/:\([^ ]\)/: \1/g
```

2) end the search term early with `\ze` This will means that the entire search term must be met for a match, but only the part before `\ze` will be higlighted / or replaced
Your final replace string should look like this:

```
%s/:\ze[^ ]/: /g
```