# Regex add space after colon

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to add a space between the colon and the character or number if there is no space already:

```
this is my sentence:hi it's midnight
this is my sentence:2012 was a good year.
this sentence should be ignored: ignore me
```

And I want it to read:

```
this is my sentence: hi it's midnight
this is my sentence: 2012 was a good year.
this sentence should be ignored: ignore me
```

I've tried this with no success.
[Regex to insert space in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405946/regex-to-insert-space-in-vim)

I can get the ":X" or ":0" using this (it doesn't match the space after the colon, which is good):

```
:[^\s]
```

But if I replace with:

```
: $0
```

It ends up like:

```
this is my sentence: :hi it's midnight
this is my sentence: :2012 was a good year.
```

I'm using http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test the pattern.

I'll be using PHP preg_replace function

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $0 captures the *entire match* (which contains the `:`!). See $1 and a capture group or, perhaps better, a *forward lookahead*.

Comment: Well in vim I believe it is:

`s/:\(\S\)/: \1/`

Comment: alternative: `str_replace(str_replace($x, ': ', ':'), ':', ': ')`. replace all "colonspace" with just a colon, then replace colons with colonspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just replace `:\s*` with `:<pretend this is a space>`:

```
preg_replace('/:\s*/', ': ', $text)
```

`:\s*` matches `:` followed by any number of spaces (or no spaces).

Comment: Thanks, btw what does the * do? - found it: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

Comment: @DiegoVieira: `\s` matches one whitespace char. `\s*` matches any number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two substitution commands to be issued in VIM:

```
 %s/:/:<space>/g

 %s/:<space><space>/:<space>/g
```

Of course, it is an overkill, that is, the number of commands to be issued is two, not one.

Here is two-in-one command:

```
:%s/:<space>*/:<space>/g
```

`<space>` is used to make it more clear as the whitespace inserted by pressing the spacebar is not printable.

Another approach to work around non-printability of space for searching:

```
:%s/:\s*/:<space>/g
```